# Where is screw/mechanism to disassemble Mico 7705 kitchen faucet?

Tags: faucet, kitchen-sink, cartridge

I need to replace the cartridge on my Mico 7705 kitchen faucet - it's been leaking. I cannot discern any screws cleverly hidden or figure out what would twist or pop off. I've found the user manual with a diagram [here](https://www.manualshelf.com/manual/mico-designs/7705-cp/dimensions-guide-english.html) but of course the model is discontinued and I can't find any tips online. Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just finsihed repairing one of these so I thought I'd share what I found.  Only the cap circled in blue above needs to be removed.  The handle simply pulls off the nylon stem of the cartridge.  The cartridge is a Kerox K40B . . .

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure, but having opened a few faucets, I would assume that the trim piece circled in red should unscrew from the handle revealing a screw that holds on the handle.  Sometimes handles are held on with set screws, but you said that non are visible.

The trim piece circled in blue will likely unscrew from the main body.  That may allow the cartridge to come right out, but there may be another (less decorative) retaining ring or screw holding it in.

They may be difficult to remove from years of water minerals drying on them.  Inspect the parts carefully to see if my suggestions are reasonable.  There is a chance you have to remove the entire faucet and loosen something from below, but that is rare.

[image: Faucet]

Comment: Unless you're referring to something inside that's visible once the red circled cap comes off, I can't see how the main, outer trim could unscrew. That would require spinning the entire spout around and it would quickly hit the wall. Of course, I haven't disassembled that many faucets...

Comment: @FreeMan oh, those are two different operations.  The red cap would just be to take off the handle.  Then only the part circled in blue might unscrew, not the whole body.  The blue part should unscrew without taking off the handle, but you’re going to take off both to replace a cartridge.